# Web Api call for React using Ajax Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, api, azure

I am new to React and Ajax and I am trying to make an api call to an Azure model but it seems to throw an error. For the time being I am using static data.
My code looks like this

example.js

```
var RecommendationInfo = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: {}};
},
loadRecommendationInfo: function(e){

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/150de299226b41698270c2ddfbc6794b/services/604f4a58cc5e44daab413ecd3dd4dd5b/execute?api-version=2.0&format=swagger',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'authorization': 'Bearer dSvR98YJPxUvGNvmVWaXcFIIBYmIA1ieSrDLde6qgpvUfV1uxq4/pT5EnfuTse1zwK1VHoOb4xg6gVVGmyFQsw=='
        },
        data: 
                {
                    'USER': 'user2',   
                    'PARENT_SKU': '1',   
                    'RATING': '1',   
        },
        success: function(result) {
            this.setState({data: result});
            console.log(result);
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2><button onClick={this.loadRecommendationInfo} > Click me</button></h2>
        </div>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
<RecommendationInfo />,
document.getElementById('container')
);
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared/css/base.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p>
    If you can see this, React is not working right. This is probably because you&apos;re viewing
    this on your file system instead of a web server. Try running
        <pre>
      python -m SimpleHTTPServer
        </pre>
    and going to     <a href="http://localhost:8000/">http://localhost:8000/    </a>.
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="../../build/react.js">    </script>
    <script src="../../build/react-dom.js">    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="example.js">    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is an error which is coming from the above code in chrome 
ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT. I am not sure why is this happening. Please help.

Comment: I think the issue is with your api endpoint, are u sure this endpoint is correct? you can use Postman to test if you can get any response from it or not.

Comment: I have already checked it with postman. I think this is some CORS problem which isn't allowing to make an api call but I am not sure.